# Trying to install postman in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install postman in Ubuntu 16.04.I ran the commands:

```
wget https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/linux64 -O postman.tar.gz 
sudo tar -xzf postman.tar.gz -C /opt
rm postman.tar.gz
sudo ln -s /opt/Postman/Postman /usr/bin/postman
```

I did not get any message about the installation. I tried to find the application in Desktop and Ubuntu Software Center. But I did not find postman. Have I done something wrong? How should I install this application?

Comment: Have you tried the POSTMAN Chrome extension? It should work.

Comment: If it is helpful please consider an upvote... Cheers

Comment: If the postman did not run in from downloaded dir, you may have to install `sudo apt install libgconf-2-4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also facing same issue.

Try this link "https://www.getpostman.com/docs/launch" and install its chrome extension and and add it extension on chrome.

Thus Postman will be installed.

Answer (score 5):

For me it's worked, follow this steps

1. **Download postman  from [here] https://www.getpostman.com/**
2. **sudo rm -R /opt/Postman** //remove old version if already exist.
3. **sudo tar -xzf postman_file_path -C /opt**
4. **Open DashHome by pressing Super key**
5. **Search for the postman, if not found, restart the system and try 4,5 steps**

Comment: How would an installation to `/opt` place an application starter file in one of the relevant locations `/usr/share/applications`, `/usr/local/share/applications`, or `~/.local/share/applications`? -1

Comment: @David, I used to like this only and working without any issue

Answer (score 4):

Run this after running your commands:

```
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/postman.desktop <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Exec=postman
Icon=/opt/Postman/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
EOL
```